# Last 2/3 task takes huge time compared to all other task in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to do sentimental analysis of comments. Program is running successfully on Spark, But the problem I am facing is out of 70 partitions 68 partitions gave result in around 20% of time compared to the time taken by last 2 partitions. I have checked my data is equally distributed on all partitions , and even checked with different sample data also.

Also I had run the code using `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)` for all dataframes, and unpersist these dataframes as soon as they are not required anymore.

I also tried increasing and decreasing the number of partitions, but still for last 2 tasks, It takes huge time. Following is the current config I am using

```
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 15 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--executor-memory 32g \
--driver-memory 8g \
--driver-cores 8 \
```

I have used KryoSerializer. Following is set in sparkConf

```
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
sparkConf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
sparkConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1024m")
```

How can I optimise, so that last 2 partitions dont take so much time?
Thanks

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] or we're just guessing at what you might have done. But I'm guessing that something different is done in those last two (coalescing the results?)

Comment: Please add the parto of your code here.

Comment: I have added configuration of Spark also, Regarding the code part, all functions will be same for all partitions,So, why it is taking different time for last 2 partitions. I am using my logic with map and flatmap functions. By the way, everytime I runs my code, the partition number which are taking time also changes, like for 70 partitions, It can be 15,65th partitions, which takes large time

Comment: Hi @LovishBansal, did you ever got answer to this? I'm facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using KYRO serialization , the default java serialization is bit slow.
When it is writing back to DISK and getting the data back , it is transferring huge amounts of data so you need to use better serialization technique.

Comment: Hey I have used KryoSerialiser also, I just now added the spark conf in my question also, for reference.

Comment: try increasing memory allocated to each executor and reduce number of executors, increase number of cores for executors . Each case is different , we have to do these different combinations.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried this increasing memory allocation and reduce number of executors, or increasing cores also , but actually the problem is code is same for all partitions, but still 2 partitions take huge time compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

You are running in client mode, try running in cluster mode. In cluster mode driver is launched with in cluster as another process.

Comment: Tried with cluster mode also, It take same time in that also

Comment: Did you check my other comment on executors ?please check and see if that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Executor processing time mostly un even based on how you partitioned your data and how busy worker node at that time. Try to relook your partitioned logic(trying to increase partition number) and increase number of core and executor memory. Its kind of specific tuning based on your specific use cases. In my case i increased partitioned number from 100 to 1000 with number of executor to 10 and core 2 solve this problem. again its depend upon how large your dataset also.

Answer (score 0):

NLP tasks can take variable amounts of time depending on the data factors.  For example, Stanford's CoreNLP takes a very long time to do NER on long sentences (time goes up with the square of the number of tokens in the sentence).

If it is a different partition each time, then I would guess that your cluster is sized in an inconvenient way: the number of executors does not divide evenly into the number of partitions.  An easy way to check this is to re-partition your 70 partitions into 700 partitions and see if the time taken is still 2 or 3 partitions, or if the time evens out.  If it is two or three partitions still, then likely it is a data issue.  If the time evens out then it was due to partition/executor mismatch.